# Given coordinates of pawns on a chess board, Count 'safe pieces', Python

Tags: python

Given the coordinates of pawns on a chess board, represented as a set of strings ie. {"b4", "d4", "f4", "c3", "e3", "g5", "d2"}, where the board is represented by rows as digits, and columns as alpha characters. determine the number of protected pawns, i.e the number of pawns with other pawns diagonally behind them on the board.
I am trying to teach myself python and have been at this task for hours. Any help would be greatly appreciated.
Here is my embarrassingly messy attempt:

```
def safe_pawns(pawns):
    count = 0
    cols = "abcdefgh"
    positions = {'a':[],'b':[],'c':[],'d':[],'e':[],'f':[],'g':[],'h':[]}
    for i in positions:
        for j in pawns:
            if i in j:
                positions[i].append(int(j[1]))
    for k in range(len(cols)-1):
        for l in positions[cols[k+1]]:
            if l +1 or l-1 in positions[cols[k]]:
                count +=1
    return count
```

Comment: What problems are you having with your code? Also, please fix the indent on your code...

Comment: Well i think i am counting pawns that protect other pieces as pieces that are protected themselves. I am producing a slightly higher number than expected.

Comment: Can you give an input and expected output for that input?

Comment: @Korem input: {"b4", "d4", "f4", "c3", "e3", "g5", "d2"}, expected output: 6.
To make things a little more clear. Here d2 is protecting e3 and c3, because it is diagonally behind them on the board.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, using letters for columns is going to cause you problems once you start doing arithmetic because you cant just do `'b' - 1`. It will be easier if you convert your set from a set of strings like `'a1'` into a set of tuples like `(1, 1)`. (Or you could zero-index, but that is outside the scope here I think).

Second, let's assume you now have a pawns set `{(2, 4), (3, 3), (4, 2), (4, 4), (5, 3), (6, 4), (7, 5)}`. You don't need that much looping. You can actually get the set of protected pieces (I'm assuming you're going from the "bottom" of the board player?) using a set expression:

```
{(x,y) for (x,y) in s if (x-1,y-1) in s or (x+1,y-1) in s}
```

And you'll find the size of that is 6.

Note: the input conversion expression I used was:

```
s = {("abcdefg".find(let) + 1, int(num)) for let, num in pawns}
```

Comment: Thanks for this, however i am unfortunately not in a position to change the input.

Comment: Added a conversion (which I used, wasn't about to type the numbers manually)

Answer (score 2):

I'm willing to bet this is your problem:

```
if l +1 or l-1 in positions[cols[k]]:
```

This doesn't mean "if l+1 is in that slot, or l-1 is in that slot". If you meant that (and you almost certainly did), you have to say that:

```
if l+1 in positions[cols[k]] or l-1 in positions[cols[k]]:
```

(There are various ways to write it indirectly, too, like `if {l+1, l-1}.intersection(positions[cols[k]])`, but I think the explicit version is the obvious way here.)